# can I make the template argument optional like the std::optional for function argument?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to have a template like:

```
template<typename T, class U, U SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG>
func1()
{
  if SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG is given
  {
    // do something special
  }
   // do something with the SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG value.
}
```

I want the function body depends on if the SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG is given or not.

I try to make the U to be std::optional, but apparently the optional cannot be the type of non-type template parameters. Is there any way I can achieve this in C++17?

Here is one of my work around, but this is more like a hack, is there any better way to do this?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> constexpr std::optional<T> typed_nullopt = std::nullopt;
template <typename T, class U = const std::optional<T> &, U SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG = typed_nullopt<T> >
void test_optional_template(T a)
{
    if constexpr (SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG == typed_nullopt<T>)
    {
        std::cout << a << " we do not have non-type arg" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << a + SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG << std::endl;
    }

}
int main()
{
    test_optional_template<int, int, 3>(5);
    test_optional_template<int>(10);
}
```

The output will be:

```
8
10 we do not have non-type arg
```

Comment: Templates are compile time, `if` is run time.... You probably need a non template function with a default argument.

Comment: In `template<typename T, class U, U SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG>` since `SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG` does not have a default initializer it must be provided by the caller.  There is no way to call the function without providing the value.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis please see my update for the detail. We can actually branch with constexpr in c++17

Comment: @NathanOliver Please refer to my update, it is some how doable. But my way is kind of hack. I want a more official way to achieve the same effect, which do not involve the std::optional

Comment: You have two answers below that are both acceptable ways of doing this.  Both of which I would suggest to you.

Answer (score 3):

Overload the function:

```
template<typename T, class U>
void func1()
{
    // Do something
}

template<typename T, class U, U SOME_NON_TYPE_ARG>
void func1()
{
    // Do something else
    func1<T, U>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
template <typename T, auto... Vs>
void func() {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Vs) <= 1);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Vs) == 1) {
        constexpr auto V = [](auto X){ return X; }(Vs...);
        // do something with V
    }
}
```

`func<int>()` won't do anything special, `func<int, 1>()` will pull out `V` as `1`, `func<int, 1, 2>()` is ill-formed.

Comment: If func<int>() and func<int, N>() can be easily separated like this. Then I could just create 2 templates as @HolyBlackCat suggested. The problem is that branches with or without the non-typed arg can be quite entangled. If I break them down to small pieces the entire thing became less readable.

Comment: @Wang I don't know what you mean by that comment. You asked for one argument, this is how you can achieve that. If that doesn't work for you, then don't do it this way.